# JFrame Maximize window

Tags: java, swing, maximize-window

I'm putting together a quick and dirty animation using swing.  I would like the window to be maximized.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Provided that you are extending JFrame:

```
public void run() {
    MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setExtendedState(myFrame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to access static field through an instance. Use `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` instead.

Comment: Huge, massive bug and issues with the above! (Well, okay fine, minor warnings with no major consequence...) Should be Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH not JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH! :)

Comment: Why do you call setVisible(true) first? Is it significant? It also works fine without (ubuntu).

Comment: Without `setVisible(true)` first, the frame is not sized correctly. I tried it both before and after `setExtendedState()`, and `setVisible()` must be first.

Comment: @Crusader Absolutely no issue here actually, since both refer to the same constant field (`JFrame` inherits from `Frame`).

Comment: @AvrDragon After experimentation, I discovered that it must the the LAST frame.setVisible(). For example, if I already have a frame.setVisible(), just plonking another one before the maximizing line of code for the purposes of making it work won't work.

Comment: on mac os x this will create a strange maximizing-animation. you can prevent it by ```calling myFrame.setSize( myFrame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds().getSize() );``` before making the frame visible.

Comment: @Crusader Good catch -- calling from Scala it makes a difference.

Comment: You are not required to extend `JFrame` to use the above code example. In fact, it's not generally a recommended approach - use composition instead. This code would work perfectly fine on a private `JFrame` instance.

Comment: @mjibson +1 - Thank you! Helped me to get rid of visual artifacts from incorrect drawing of the lower and right side of the frame in maximaized state.

Answer (score 18):

Something like `this.setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public Test()
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment env =
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        this.setMaximizedBounds(env.getMaximumWindowBounds());
        this.setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        Test t = new Test();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `|` for? Does it do one, and if that fails it does the other? Or are you indicating programmer choice (I.e. pick one of A|B to go in this call?) I've not seen this syntax before.

Comment: @Pureferret it is the "bitwise inclusive OR" operator, which  copies a bit if it exists in either operand. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm)

Answer (score 16):

If you're using a JFrame, try this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//...
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 7):

How about [`JFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int))?

Answer (score 2):

The way to set JFrame to full-screen, is to set [`MAXIMIZED_BOTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#MAXIMIZED_BOTH) option which stands for `MAXIMIZED_VERT | MAXIMIZED_HORIZ`, which respectively set the frame to maximize vertically and horizontally

```
package Example;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class JFrameExample
{
    static JFrame frame;
    static GraphicsConfiguration gc;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        frame = new JFrame(gc);
        frame.setTitle("Full Screen Example");
        frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        JButton button = new JButton("exit");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            JFrameExample.frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }});

        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i like this version:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final GraphicsConfiguration config = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();

        final int left = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config).left;
        final int right = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config).right;
        final int top = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config).top;
        final int bottom = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config).bottom;

        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        final int width = screenSize.width - left - right;
        final int height = screenSize.height - top - bottom;

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(width,height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this version. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the solutions in this thread and the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258207/243373), but simply calling `setExtendedState(getExtendedState()|Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` right after calling `setVisible(true);` apparently does not work for my environment (Windows 10, JDK 1.8, my taskbar is on the right side of my screen). Doing it this way still leaves a tiny space on the left, right and bottom .

What did work for me however, is calling `setExtendedState(...` when the window is activated, like so:

```
public class SomeFrame extends JFrame {

    public SomeFrame() {
        // ...
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        // if you are calling setSize() for fallback size, do that here
        addWindowListener (
            new WindowAdapter() {
                private boolean shown = false;
                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we) {
                    if(shown) return;
                    shown = true;
                    setExtendedState(getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue on Windows 10 with the taskbar on the bottom of the screen. The window was too high and therefore overlapped by the taskbar. Your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code:

```
public void setMaximized(boolean maximized){
    if(maximized){
        DisplayMode mode = this.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice().getDisplayMode();
        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(this.getGraphicsConfiguration());
        this.setMaximizedBounds(new Rectangle(
                mode.getWidth() - insets.right - insets.left, 
                mode.getHeight() - insets.top - insets.bottom
        ));
        this.setExtendedState(this.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }else{
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

This options worked the best of all the options, including multiple monitor support. The only flaw this has is that the taskbar offset is used on all monitors is some configurations.

Answer (score 0):

@kgiannakakis answer is fully correct, but if someone stuck into this problem and uses **Java 6** on **Linux** (by example, Mint 19 Cinnamon), *MAXIMIZED_BOTH* state is sometimes not applied.

You could try to call [pack()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) method after setting this state.

Code example:

```
public MainFrame() {
    setContentPane(contentPanel); //some JPanel is here
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
    setSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    pack();
}
```

This is not necessary if you are using Java 7+ or Java 6 on Windows.