# ExtendedState not returning to maximized/re-centered condition

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowstate

When I create my `JFrame`, I start out with it maximized and in the center of the window using:
`setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`
`setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

However, when I move my frame from the docked location to somewhere else on the screen, nothing happens when I try to resize/recenter it back to it's maximized location using the maximize button in the title bar. I'm on a Mac and clicking the green + button or double-clicking the title bar does nothing to affect the frame's state or location.

I can get it to recenter if I use a `WindowStateListener` to change the frame's size based on the state. But I would like to keep the frame the same size if moving it from the maximized state to a normal state.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is get my frame to register a new window size if it moves between different screen resolutions. So far, the issue I'm running into is the inability to resize/re-center to a similar resolution without adjusting the frame size itself.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: For your first paragraph: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40438927/1803551).